# How to handle different iterator value types using the same function

Tags: boost, c++11

For below code:

```
template < class _InIt,
           class _Ty,
           class _Fn2 > inline
_Ty accumulateSimplePtr(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Ty _Val, _Fn2 _Func)
{
    // return sum of _Val and all in [_First, _Last), using _Func
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
    {
        if (is_class<std::iterator_traits<_InIt>::value_type>::value)
            _Val = _Func(_Val, (*_First)());
        else
            _Val = _Func(_Val, *_First);//This line doesn't work...
    }
    return (_Val);
}
```

I want the code to work both for `_InIt` pointing to `double`, and for pointing to a class.
If pointing to a class, I will use `(*_First)()` to get the data(assuming the class has operator() that returns `double`), otherwise I simply use `*_First` to get the data.

Is there any way to use `boost::is_class` or any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea. I'd prefer to write two different functions to handle two different types like this:

```
// Also, note, your function is very similar to 
// std::accumulate from numeric header

std::vector<Foo> v1{3.14159, 1.77245385};
std::accumulate
(
    v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0.,
    [] (double i, const Foo& f) { return i + f(); }
);

std::vector<double> v2{3.14159, 1.77245385};
std::accumulate(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0.);
```

But if you don't want to do this, I'd suggest write a function wrapper:

```
namespace detail
{

template <class F, class V, class T>
auto function_wrapper(F&& f, V&& v, T&& t)
    ->  typename std::enable_if
        <
            std::is_class<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value,
            typename std::remove_reference<V>::type
        >::type
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<V>(v), std::forward<T>(t)());
}

template <class F, class V, class T>
auto function_wrapper(F&& f, V&& v, T&& t)
    ->  typename std::enable_if
        <
            !std::is_class<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value,
            typename std::remove_reference<V>::type
        >::type
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<V>(v), std::forward<T>(t));
}

} // namespace detail

template < class _InIt,
           class _Ty,
           class _Fn2 > inline
_Ty accumulateSimplePtr(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Ty _Val, _Fn2 _Func)
{
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        _Val = detail::function_wrapper(_Func, _Val, *_First);
    return (_Val);
}

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(double d): _d(d)
    {

    }

    double operator() () const
    {
        return _d;
    }

private:
    double _d;
};


int main()
{
    auto f = [] (double a, double b) { return a + b; };

    std::vector<Foo> v1{3.14159, 1.77245385};
    std::cout << accumulateSimplePtr(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0., f) << std::endl;

    std::vector<double> v2{3.14159, 1.77245385};
    std::cout << accumulateSimplePtr(v2.begin(), v2.end(), 0., f) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::enable_if`, applied to the return type of the
template function, to direct the compiler to instantiate
different functions depending on whether the value_type is a class or
not, like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

// Compiler will choose this one when the value_type is a class
template < class _InIt,
           class _Ty,
           class _Fn2
>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_class<
        typename std::iterator_traits<_InIt>::value_type
    >::value,
    _Ty
>::type
accumulateSimplePtr(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Ty _Val, _Fn2 _Func)
{
    // return sum of _Val and all in [_First, _Last), using _Func
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First) {
        _Val = _Func(_Val, (*_First)());
    }
    return (_Val);
}

// Compiler will choose this one when the value_type is not a class
template < class _InIt,
           class _Ty,
           class _Fn2
>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_class<
        typename std::iterator_traits<_InIt>::value_type
    >::value,
    _Ty
>::type
accumulateSimplePtr(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Ty _Val, _Fn2 _Func)
{
    // return sum of _Val and all in [_First, _Last), using _Func
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First) {
        _Val = _Func(_Val, *_First);
    }
    return (_Val);
}
```

Read about `std::enable_if` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

The way that you tried to do this does not work because it requires the
compiler to *compile* both the *is_a_class" and the *is_not_a_class* branches
of the `if`, even though they cannot both compile. `std::enable_if` causes
only the correct function to be compiled.

Please note that you ought not to use identifiers beginning with an underscore
and uppercase letter as all such identifiers are reserved for the compiler and
its library. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1362568).